# Dynamically expanding empty space?

Tags: android, layout, space, expand

Is there a way to separate upper content from lower content on the screen?  So that no matter what's in the upper area the lower area remains against the bottom of the screen.  I've tried gravity=bottom and things like that.  I've tried inserting a layout of some kind in between top and bottom hoping it would stay expanded (thus pushing the two apart).  Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: RelativeLayout

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="TOP"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:text="BOTTOM"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That works great, I should open my eyes :).  it does the trick in portrait, but when in landscape the bottom aligned stuff overlaps the top stuff.  Is there a way to change that in the onCreate of the activity so that if it's landscape it's false and if portrait its true?  Thanks for the help

Comment: Try to use other properties like android:layout_below and above. The best would be if you did portrait and landscape layouts separately.